# Form "submit" working in IE but not Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a sign up form on my site which works OK in IE but does not work in Firefox or Chrome. I have tried looking through other forum posts here with similar problems but still can't get my head round this silly problem. (I am not a code writer).

Here is the code

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function validate_form(){
{validation_text}
else{
        return true;
    }
}
var str_vars = '';
function all_fields(){
    str_vars = '';
    el = document.form1;
    for (var i = 0; i < el.elements.length; i++) {
        if (el.elements[i].value != '')
        str_vars += el.elements[i].name+'='+el.elements[i].value+'&';
    }
    str_vars = str_vars.substr(0,str_vars.length-15);;
}
</script>
<div id="div_form" name="div_form">
<form id="form1" name="formx" method="{send_method}" action="{form_switch}">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table border="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
{error}
{signup_list}
<tr>
    <td align="right">{description_country} &nbsp;</td>
    <td>{shiping_country_list}{required_country}</td>
  </tr>
<tr><td align="right"> {promo}</td></tr>
 {code_signup}
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div align="center">
      <input name="terms" id="terms" value="1" type="checkbox">
      <label for="terms">I accept the <a href="terms.php" target="_blank">terms &amp; conditions</a></label>
    </div></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div align="center">
{captcha}</td>
    </tr>
    {arp_fields}
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">*</div><br></td>
    <td width="332">Denotes required</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div align="right">
 <input name="Submit" value="Submit" type="button" onclick="{request}{request_email}{form2items}">
        </div></td>
    <td> <br></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of

```
el = document.form1;
```

try

```
 el = document.getElementById('form1');
```

I can't see all the JS so it is hard to guess, but one other thing to try is to change the name of the submit button from `name="Submit"` to something else like `name="submitForm"`.  If form.submit() is getting called somewhere in the script this can cause problems.

Your validate function should look something like this:

```
function validate_form(){
var form = document.getElementById('form1');
err = 'The following fields are not correct filled:\n';

if (form.first_name.value == ''){
    err += 'No First Name.\n';
}

if (emailCheck(form.email.value) == false){
    err += 'No Valid email.\n';
}

if (form.terms.checked != true){                
    err += 'You did not agree with the terms.\n';
}

if (err != 'The following fields are not correct filled:\n'){
    alert (err);
    return false;
}

else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Lastly, change your submit button to this:
    `<input name="Submit" value="Submit" type="button" onclick="if (validate_form()) document.getElementById('form1').submit();">`

Comment: added one more thing for you to try

Comment: Hi @robbieAreBest thanks for taking the time. I cant change the "submit" name as that would involve me having to change several other bits of code in the rest of the site I am working on.  the page that the code is on is here if that will help identify the problem. http://appattract.com/signup_jv.php

Comment: I'm getting an error here: `if (document.form1.first_name.value == ''){` - it is the same issue I noted above.  You should change this reference to something like `if (document.getElementById('form1').first_name.value == ''){` and others like it.

Comment: Hi @robbieAreBest just tried your code and It still only works in IE so maybe the error lies elsewhere. wiers sittuation. why dont all the browser bosses get together and agree a strategy that works LOL

Comment: That would be nice.  You also have the same issue in the onclick event on your submit button. `document.form1`.  I noticed that at least the validation pops up now, so that is progress.

Comment: hey @robbieAreBest  Whoo Hoo man....You did it !! it works now. I just added the last bit of code for the submit button and ran a test in 4 different browsers and it works in them all now...you are my HERO !!  I had spent hours trying to get that darn thing to work !!! I am really greatful...

Comment: Glad everything worked out for you! don't forget to accept my answer, I could use some more points :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch @robbieAreBest..I accepted your answer (i thinK) i ticked it so I assume that is correct. If I run into more problems i,ll give you a nudge...